# Removing jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using this timepicker: http://labs.perifer.se/timedatepicker/ for one of my intrasite
I am enabling the timepicker as mentioned in the example by using

```
<select id="change_type">
    <option value="1">Time</option>
    <option value="2">Text</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="time1" size="10">
$("#time1").timePicker();
```

Based on a dropdown list I want to make the field time1 as either time/simple text.
Is there a way where I can remove the time picker to make the field as simple text?

TIA

Bittu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using Javascript to simply remove the #time1 field then add in a new one with the same ID, setting its value (and any attributes) to the same as the original.

Comment: cool.. it's simple and it works when i tried it on a test page. I will update you once I have it working on my site :)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#time1").timePicker('destroy');` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

How about having two fields, one plain and one datepicker()'ed, and hide/show them as needed?

Alternatively, consider the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), which has a `destroy` method which resets the target element.

Comment: Unfortunately, the jQuery UI datepicker does not include a timepicker, but consider using this one: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Cito/N3dst4: Thanks for the links, but I have to use this plugin just because it is simple and lists out all the values as a dropdown. I don't have an option to move to another plugin :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.time-picker').remove()` to remove the time-picker function from your page.

Comment: I tried that.. but when I change the dropdown value to time again, the timepicker won't show up.

Comment: Ah, right. In addition to that, you need to ``delete $('#time1')[0].timePicker``.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one:

```
var element = document.getElementById("TIME-PICKER-ID");
var clonedElement = element.cloneNode(true);
var parentElement = element.parentNode;
parentElement.replaceChild(clonedElement, element);
```